# SQL: converting a + separated list to an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a table with a column of `+` separated strings in our database. Is there anyway to select the sum of each row? i.e., say we have `5212667+5212662`; I'd like to select `10425329`.

I tried `CONVERT(INT, ColumnAddList)`, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data *and* desired results.

Comment: select 5212667+5212662 it is explicit  conversion it won't convert into int

Comment: Don't store data like that is the answer. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: SQL server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server` you could split and calculate sum:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), col VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO tab(col) VALUES('5212667+5212662'),('1+2+3'),('2'), (NULL), ('1+-1');

SELECT *
FROM tab
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT [result] = SUM( Split.a.value('.', 'BIGINT'))
    FROM (SELECT [X] = CAST ('<M>'+REPLACE(col, '+', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML)) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY X.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
) AS s;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/RVW97299)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║       col       ║  result  ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ 5212667+5212662 ║ 10425329 ║
║  2 ║ 1+2+3           ║ 6        ║
║  3 ║ 2               ║ 2        ║
║  4 ║ NULL            ║ NULL     ║
║  5 ║ 1+-1            ║ 0        ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩══════════╝
```

---

The correct way is to normalize your table schema.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
@sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
 , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
 ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
 DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
 WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT
     @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX
      (@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX
      (@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

  IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
    INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
  END

 IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
     INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
     RETURN
  END
GO

declare @table table (Val varchar(2000))
insert into @table values('1+1+1+')
insert into @table values('2+2+2+')
insert into @table values('3+3+3+')
insert into @table values('4+4+4+')
select Val, (select sum(convert(decimal(10,2),item)) from dbo.fnSplit(val,'+') ) as summ from @table
```

Hope this helps!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: This works but that type of splitter is horribly inefficient. There is not need to resort to looping to split delimited strings. Here are number of better options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: But the solution with common table function is generic for all, and the link which you provided has many solutions but all are related to specific table or table column and not the generic. And if you look at the actual execution plan after executing the last query in my answer, it costs very less as compared to other solution from that link

Comment: HUH??? The splitters in there are generic. The while loop splitter posted here is also generic but horribly slow.

Comment: There is no way in the world that the function you posted is going to outperform a set-based splitter. The performance tests have been done hundreds if not thousands of times. Just compare your solution to the one posted above by lad2025.